# How to enable LinkButton after 10 seconds Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

When I click on LinkButton `lbUpVoteUndo` it should disable for 10 seconds. I have tried it in c# code-behind. Is there another way to do same thing?

```
protected void lbUpVoteUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbUpVoteUndo.Enabled = false;

    if(/* check for 10 seconds */)
    {
        lbUpVoteUndo.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to assume this is WebForms, since you haven't specified.  If you're trying to load the page, then 10 seconds later have the button enable, this will not be possible with server code.  The code you've posted will wait 10 seconds to execute, then the page will be loaded with the button enabled or disabled.

Comment: Its not related to `WebForms`. It is simple `linkbutton` to which I click.

Comment: I'd recommend doing this with javascript if you can, otherwise, you're gonna need to wrap that button in an UpdatePanel and I'm not sure if you have that implemented.

Comment: @Asif.Ali  -  you could try looking it up as well.  You might learn something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript can do this for you. These two lines of code will do it for you:

```
function DisableFor10Seconds() {
      document.getElementById("<% lbUpVoteUndo.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("<% lbUpVoteUndo.ClientID %>").disabled = false;},10000);
}
```

It's been awhile since I worked on .NET webforms but in your  control I believe you could do something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpVoteUndo" OnClientClick="Disablefor10Seconds();" />
```

I'd like to add that 10 seconds is a long time, are you expecting the user to wait around for 10 seconds? For instance if the user hits refresh the button will become enabled again.  If you want to keep it disabled for 10 seconds no matter what happens, then you should probably store a flag in Session or Cache which can then set a client side element with the timer perhaps.

Comment: it showing error in `DisableFor10Seconds` function can you please edit it

Comment: Element `Style` is missing its closing tags erroe

Comment: Actually this won't work because lnkButton creates an <a> I believe and you can't disable that this way.  Let me think of something else.  If you look here you'll see it working with a button: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt82r5zj/8/

Comment: You need `<% lblUpvoteUndo.ClientID %>` (see the closing `%>`), twice

Comment: Solid answer - also agreed on the 10 seconds wait-time being pointless since a refresh will entirely circumvent this measure.

Answer (score 0):

**Use javascript function -**

In HTML, Add below code with your button control -

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.disabled='true'; this.value='Please wait...';"
```

In .CS cdoe, Use this in you button click event -

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have .aspx page and your code in server side means .cs file. right ?

Comment: Yes, I want to handle it in `.cs` file.

Comment: Ok. You can use UseSubmitBehavior="false" of your button. like this -             UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.disabled='true'; this.value='Please wait...';". And in your .cs code write code Thread.Sleep(3000);

Comment: If you are not able to understand to my code then please let me know. I will edit code in my answer.

Comment: Please check answer.